# If $\vec{x}_k \to \vec{0}$, and $\vec{y}_k$ is bounded then $\vec{x}_k \cdot \vec{y}_k\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would appreciate if you could please look at my proof and let me know if it's OK.

> Proof:
>
> $\vec{x}_k\to\vec{0}$ implies that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lVert \vec{x}_k\lVert <\varepsilon$ for $k>N$. $\vec{y}_k$ is bounded implies that $\exists C>0$ such that $\lVert \vec{y}_k\lVert \le C$. Let $\tilde\varepsilon = \varepsilon C.$ Now, $\lvert\vec{x}_k \cdot \vec{y}_k\lvert \leq \lVert \vec{x}_k\lVert \lVert \vec{y}_k\lVert < \varepsilon C = \tilde\varepsilon $ (by Cauchy-Schwartz) for $k >N$. Thus $\vec{x}_k \cdot \vec{y}_k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: there is typo at $\|\vec x_k \| \le C$. Otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Comment: When you say $\lVert \vec{x}_k\lVert \lVert \vec{y}_k\lVert < \varepsilon C$ maybe you should mention that it's true for $k>N$.

Answer (score 0):

It is bit confusing. You can write: We have $C>0$ such that $\|y_{k}\|\leq C$. For all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x_{k}\|<\frac{\epsilon}{C}$ for all $k>N$. Therefore, for all $k>N$, $$|x_{k}y_{k}|\leq\|x_{k}\|\|y_{k}\|<\epsilon$$

Comment: well... I agree that it is neater to take $N$ so that $\|x_k\|<\epsilon/C$ for $k\geq N$. However, I think that omitting justifications like "because $x_n\to 0$" or "by Cauchy-Schwartz" is *not* a good thing.

Comment: @Surb I quoted just what should improve , which was the issue of $\epsilon$